# How to find most popular product

Tags: machine-learning

This is more like a general, brainstroming query rather than a question.
    So here it goes.
Suppose, I have 1000 items which I can sell on a website at any given day.
On any given day, I can sell (lets say) only 100 items..
And lets say, the obvious goal is to sell the maximum number of products any given day (maximimzing revenue).. 
What is the best way to solve this problem. The problem being.. how do i select which 100 products of 1000 to select??I am sure, with this information it is pretty hard.. If I have to solve it using machine learning, which category will this problem fall into.
This is not supervised learning.. ?
Basically, I am just looking for the people around here to throw me some ideas.. :)
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a variation of the [multi-armed bandit problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit). The most basic way of optimizing your profit is to pick a number ε є [0,1], then for each of the products you select choose the most popular one with probability (1-ε) or random with probability ε. This way, over time, you will have increasingly accurate popularity estimates for each product, while keeping your total profits high. More sophisticated approaches include tracking [upper confidence bounds](http://www.springerlink.com/index/L7V1647363415H1T.pdf) on product popularity.

Answer (score 1):

Naive approach is store for each product the probability of being sold (how many times shown how many time solt). And based on those probability select 100 among 1000. So any product has a change to be selected and the changes is equal to its propability. BTW for this probability it is better to use [lower confidence bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval). So product which is sold 70 from 100 times is better then product which sold 7 from 10.

Comment: but I think there will be one problem in this approach.. The items which will have the higher probability of being sold will always be the ones who made it on the stores.. and hence the item which is at 999/1000 will never be listed....It will be sort of entering in a loop.. that items who made it to the store.. get a chance to be sold.. and then there probability increases and then next time, they are again higher.. ? right??

Comment: Yes, it will follow approach "Winner takes all". So it will maximize your profit, but probabilities will not be really accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I was inspired by this post to implement bunch of  multi-arm bandit algorithms in Hadoop as part of my open source Hadoop based machine learning project avenir on github. I also posted a blog recently which is about  finding optimum product price using some the implemented algorithms.

http://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2013/08/25/bandits-know-the-best-product-price/

https://github.com/pranab/avenir

Answer (score 0):

well where would you get ur data on the items from? If for example you had some sales figures for each item you would simply create a column for that in the database then `SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY 'number_sold' DESC LIMIT 100` and update it with +1 every time an item is sold

Comment: Number sold is not a good value to order by, because it depends on the number of times a product has been put on display.

Comment: yeah but this is inevitable unless ur gonna evenly rotate the items until you have data, unless of course you have previous sales data, if not you dont really have much to go on!